# How to do not call a JS function after loading the page

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, pageload

I want to load a JS function only when my php code call this function, but not when you visit the page for the first time. My code looks like this:

```
   <?php
      function runMyFunction() {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> JSfunction(); </script>'; 
      }
   ?>


    <script>
    
    JSfunction();
    function JSfunction(){
        // Code in my function
    }

    </script>
```

The problem is that the function JSfunction() is called as soon as the page (index.html) is loaded. But I only want to execute the function with my PHP code, which is called after clicking a button. I would be glad about an answer.

Comment: PHP runs on your server, JavaScript runs in the browser.

Comment: Get rid of `runMyFunction`. Add the code of that function to your click event handler. Won't fire on load, instead will fire on click.

Answer (score 0):

bind the click event on the button to an ajax call, which calls your php code and returns JSON saying whether to go ahead or not.

The other method for this is to have this type of php code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['myvar'])){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
//call your javascript here
</script
<?php
}
?>
```

With that in place have clicking the button reload the page with the GET variable myvar appended to the url.

Example: https://example.com?myvar=1